# savingloan() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loanname'

Tags: django

I am trying to submit the form after entering the details but after submitting, it shows and error like

> unexpected arguments 'loanname' keywords in loanform(loanname = name,
>   email = email, mobile = mobile, scheme = scheme, city = city, msg =
>   msg) method.

## My Model.Py File

```
class loanform(models.Model):
    loanname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    scheme = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.loanname
```

## My View.Py File

```
def loan_form(request):
    print("Loan form is submitted successfully!")
    name = request.POST["name"]
    email = request.POST["email"]
    mobile = request.POST["mobile"]
    scheme = request.POST["scheme"]
    city = request.POST["city"]
    msg = request.POST["msg"]

    lnform = loanform(loanname = name, email = email, mobile = mobile, scheme = scheme, city = city, msg = msg)
    lnform.save()

    return render(request,'loanform.html')
```

## My Url.Py File

```
path('loan_form/', views.loan_form, name='loan_form')
```

Comment: this shouldn't happen. copy the whole traceback and paste it here

Comment: You can try to create a loanform object from django shell first passing all arguments.

Comment: Which traceback would i pasted here -- Vaibhav Vishal

Comment: Can u please tell me how to pass arguments from django shell.. Arindam Roychowdhury